# How to build a table where each cell is built using the 2 dimensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dictionary, activerecord, hash

**Desired output**

Each User has child Plan which has child PlanDate objects. PlanDate has an attribute `ddate` which is just a date. Plan has an attribute `mtype` that can either be `M`, `V`, or `C` (haha MVC, subconscious techy much?). For a given week (let's just say the current week), I'd like to print out a table that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  User  |  Mon  |  Tue  |  Wed  |  Thu  |  Fri  | Other attributes of User
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Eric  |   M   |       |   M   |       |   M   |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Erin  |   V   |   V   |   V   |   V   |   V   |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Jace  |       |   C   |   C   |       |       |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Kris  |   C   |       |       |       |       |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Tina  |   V   |       |   V   |       |   V   |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Lily  |   M   |   M   |   M   |   M   |   M   |  ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The order of the Users on the rows doesn't really matter to me; I may add Ransack gem to make it ordered, but for now ignore. A given User may not have PlanDates with a `ddate` for every day in a given week, and certainly there's no relationship between the PlanDates across Users.

**Proposed options**

I feel like there are two options:

1. In the view, print the column headers with a `data-attribute` of the day in question, and print the row headers with a `data-attribute` of the user id in question (will have to first select all the users who do have a grandchild PlanDate with a `ddate` somewhere in the current week). Then in the intersection, use the two `data-attributes` to query ActiveRecord.
2. In the model, generate a data hash that can create the table, and then pass that hash to the view via the controller.

Option 1 makes more intuitive sense to me having been a lifelong Excel user, but it breaks MVC entirely, so I'm trying to go with Option 2, and the challenges below are related to Option 2. That said if you can make a case for Option 1 go for it! I feel like if you can convince me to do Option 1, I can implement it without the same problems...

**Challenges with Option 2**

I can build a hash with one dimension as a key, and a hash of the other dimension as an array. For example, if the days of the current week were used as the key:

```
{
  Mon => [Eric, Erin, Kris, Tina, Lily],
  Tue => [Erin, Jace, Lily]
  Wed => [Eric, Erin, Jace, Kris, Lily],
  Thu => [Erin, Lily],
  Fri => [Eric, Erin, Tina, Lily]
}
```

But the problem is once I get there, I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that there are blanks in the data... If I were to convert the hash above into a table, I would only know how to make the Users appear as a list under each date; but then that wouldn't look like my desired output at all, because there wouldn't be gaps in the data. For example on Monday, there's no Jace, but there needs to be a blank space for Jace so that it's easy for the Viewer to look across and see, ah there's no Jace on Monday, but there is a Jace on Tuesday and Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

Oh actually I just needed a minute to think logically about this... I just need a nested hash, one with the first dimension, one with the second. So a method like this:

```
def plan_table
    # 1 : get an array of the current week's dates
    week = (Date.today.at_beginning_of_week..(Date.today.at_end_of_week-2.days)).map { |d| d }
    # 2 : find all the users (plucking the id) that have a plan date in the current week
    current_week_users = User.select { |u| u.plans.select { |p| p.plan_dates.select { |pd| week.include? pd.ddate.to_date }.count > 0 }.count > 0 }.map(&:id)
    # 3: build the hash
    @week_table = Hash.new
    week.each do |day|
        @week_table[day] = {}
        current_week_users.each do |user_id|
            # for each user in the has we built already, we have to check if that user has a pd that: 1) falls on this date, 2) has a non canceled plan, 3) has a user that matches this current user. The extra checks for user_id and plan_id are my ole' paranoia about objects being created without parents
            potential_pd = PlanDate.select { |pd| pd.ddate.to_date == day && pd.plan_id != nil && pd.plan.status != "canceled" && pd.plan.user_id != nil && pd.plan.user.id == user_id }
            if potential_pd == [] 
                @week_table[day][user_id] = ""
            else
                @week_table[day][user_id] = potential_pd.first.plan.mtype
            end
        end
    end
    return @week_table
end
```